# C# server.AcceptTcpClient and Listbox

Tags: c#, tcp, listbox

I'm writing a simple TCP-Connection software.

Firstly, I wrote the server in a ConsoleApp and it workes quite well.
Now I wanted to port it to a form application, but when a client connects, it does not add a new entry in my ListBox, on the Console it workes well.
I tried to write in the Load function as well as writing it in a separate Thread.
Both don't work.

In the Console it worked like this, and the Console wrote "User connected":

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int PORT = 14758;

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);


        try
        {
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started");
        } catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error", Ex);
        }

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("User connected");
```

Now in my form App it does not work like this:

```
        public frmMainServer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread serverStart = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start_Server));
        serverStart.Start();
        serverStart.Join();

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        addItem("User connected");
    }
```

As said before, I tried to write the last 2 lines in the Thread, too, but it didn't help.

I actually think I CAN connect to the server, so why does it not add the line?

addItem function:

```
        private void addItem(string item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
        listStatus.DataSource = _items;
    }
```

Comment: I think you have 2 problems here, not 1: (1) why doesn't the text get added to the listbox and (2) how to design a form that can do stuff in the background. For the first topic - tell us what happens in 'addItem' ?

Comment: Oh, you are right! I edited the function!